# Mocha Testing Angular referenceError: Zone is not defined

Tags: angular, mocha.js

I am trying to run a test on Angular 4.0.0 components and I am using Mocha. I am receiving the following error:

```
var FakeAsyncTestZoneSpec = Zone['FakeAsyncTestZoneSpec'];

ReferenceError: Zone is not defined`
```

here is my test code:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core';
import {SocketService} from '../src/app/services/socket.service';
import 'mocha';


describe('BannerComponent (inline template)', () => {

let comp:    SocketService;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<SocketService>;
let de:      DebugElement;
let el:      HTMLElement;

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ SocketService ], // declare the test component
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SocketService);

    comp = fixture.componentInstance; // BannerComponent test instance

    // query for the title <h1> by CSS element selector
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));
    el = de.nativeElement;
   });
});
```

I have been scratching my head for a bit now, I have gone through every message board and tutorial I could find, the best of my sleuthing has come down to, Zone.js is not being instantiated soon enough to define `Zone`. I tried to `import 'zone.js'` inside my test code but it had no affect. 
Would anyone know how to bypass or fix this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The radzen blog setup is out dated.

Here is a setup to launch test with mocha-webpack plugin :

```
    require('core-js/es6');
    require('core-js/es7/reflect');
    require('zone.js/dist/zone-node');
    require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
    require('zone.js/dist/proxy');
    require('zone.js/dist/sync-test');
    require('zone.js/dist/async-test');
    require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test');

    const testing = require('@angular/core/testing');
    const browser = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing');

    testing.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(browser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule, browser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());

    const jsdom=  require("jsdom");
    const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

    const window = (new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>')).window;
    const document = window.document;

    global.window = window;
    global.document = document;
    global.HTMLElement = window.HTMLElement;
    global.XMLHttpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest;
    global.Node = window.Node;
```

I'm using :

```
    Angular v4.1.1.
    Webpack v2.2.1.
    jsdom v10.1.0.
    mocha-webpack.
```

I've wrote a thread explaining how to setup webpack configuration to test an Angular application with Mocha, Chai and sinon. It's work with Angular 4+ release.

http://hichambi.github.io/2016/12/27/testing-angular2-with-webpack-mocha-on-browser-and-node.html

Hope that will help you.

Comment: Sorry, I've detailed my answer. I hope that it's clear now. Thanks.

Comment: Looks better now, thanks. (Not my downvote btw, I lack domain knowledge to vote on this.)

Comment: Perfect, clean and intuitive. Thank you.

Comment: I also wrote you in your detailed answer in the comment section. I tried to update this with Angular 5 but no luck. Any wise words?

Comment: I've updated the configuration to support Angular 5+ : https://github.com/HichamBI/Angular-testing-webpack-mocha-chai-sinon

Answer (score 1):

I found this shim at http://www.radzen.com/blog/testing-angular-webpack-mocha/

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom')

var document = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');

var window = document.defaultView;

global.document = document;
global.HTMLElement = window.HTMLElement;
global.XMLHttpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest;

require('core-js/es6');
require('core-js/es7/reflect');

require('zone.js/dist/zone');
require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
require('zone.js/dist/proxy');
require('zone.js/dist/sync-test');
require('zone.js/dist/async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test');

var testing = require('@angular/core/testing');
var browser = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing');
```

and needed to apply it "correctly" using mocha's cli command flag `--require`